# Regular vs LALR(1): what is faster

Tags: regular-languages, efficiency, parsers

Supposing we have two grammars which define the same languge: regular one and LALR(1) one.

Both regular and LALR(1) algorithms are O(n) where n is input length.

Regexps are usually preferred for parsing regular languages. Why? Is there a formal proof (or maybe that's obvious) that they are faster?

Comment: It's usually the case that algorithms handling a vastly more complicated situation are slower. You definitely shouldn't expect a formal proof of anything, though, since (1) it really depends on the model of computation and (2) lower bounds are impossible. Instead, people conduct experiments and let their empirical results be known.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any empirical results on this topic? (Maybe some links)

Comment: Note that parsing regular languages (via DFA, I assume) and using regexps (the practical ones) is not the same thing. Which do you want to consider? Also, are we allowed to preprocess something (e.g. create a DFA)?

Comment: I'm trying to compare parsing regular languages using DFA and parsing regular languages using LR/SLR/LALR: if the second way can be more efficient (faster), then why should we use DFA at all. (I don't quite understand where are you going to use preprocessing).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for favoring regular expressions over LALR(1) grammars for accepting simple grammars stems from the time needed to *build* an LALR(1) automaton. Let $m$ denote the size of the grammar which is used to build the automata for accepting the language defined by said grammar. If you need to build up the accepting automaton during runtime you will probably want to use regular expressions because building up an LALR(1) automaton will take $O(m\cdot 2^m)$ which does not include the necessary testing if the input grammar even is LALR(1) ($O(m^3)$). Regular expressions instead can be build up quite easily, the check can occur during conversion (see [1] , re2post).

Adding to the speed gained when building up different regular expressions during different program runs modern regular expressions, mostly PCRE, are NP-Complete, thus very powerful (see for instance [2]). Additionally, with most languages supporting regular expressions there also is an interactive environment to check if the regular expression really expresses your intention, which is more efficient from a programmer's perspective than to write the grammar, generate the parser and do a test and then reiterate the process. I believe this to be the main reason for using regular expressions over LALR(1) grammars.

If you are interested in the implementation and runtime aspects of grammars [3] might also be of interest to you.

[1] http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/

[2] http://nikic.github.com/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html

[3] Gerhard Goos, William Waite, Compiler Construction, Springer, Jan 1984 ( symbolaris.com/course/Compilers/waitegoos.pdf)

Comment: Actually, many regexp matching algorithms used in practice run into *huge* trouble if the regexp is ambiguous, so I don't think a general statement can be made here.

Comment: The time to build the automaton is inmaterial if you are going to the trouble. The DFA uses less resources (no memory for stack) and is faster (less operarions per symbol).

Comment: Concerning the first comment, this is what [1] is all about and is only true for the NP-complete ones (the ones with backtracking).

Comment: cberg, thank you for useful links! In my case, I've developed two parser generators: one that creates parsers for regular languages and one that creates parsers for LALR(1) languages. Speed of the generated parser is the main point for me. So I don't have the trouble of **building** parser anyway. I'm gonna held some experiments myself but before that I wanted know what people have already done.

Comment: Again, saying "parsing regular expressions" I mean only DFA and not all the extensions used in many regexp libs.

Comment: vonbrand, I don't understend if you are talking about time/space to build parser or time/space to run it.

Comment: Raphael, what do you mean by "ambigous" regexp? One string matching two or more regexps in grammar?

Comment: @cberg, your comment about building LALR(1) parsers is at best misleading. First, the exponential limit is true, but rarely (or never) occurs in practical grammars. (Otherwise, yacc would only run on supercomputers.) Second, the standard LALR(1) construction will terminate with failure if the grammar is not LALR(1), so it's not necessary to test the grammar first. Finally, in theory at least, the DFA construction for regular expressions can also be exponential in the size of the regular expression.

Comment: @rici: you are quite right, I forgot to mention that this is usually not the case. Thanks for adding this clarification.

Comment: @skvadrik: concerning ambigous regexp see the motivating example under [1] of my original post (the first article there). Do you build up your DFA directly or via NFA?

Comment: I build DFA via NFA. I don't support backreferences.